# How to properly convert Solid.Section() results into Regions in Eyeshot?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

When trying to get a section of a `devDept.Eyeshot.Entities.Mesh` or `devDept.Eyeshot.Entities.Solid` using the `.Section(Plane, double)` method, we get an `ICurve[]`.

If the result is **multiple closed curves**, to draw the `ICurve[]`, I convert all the `ICurve`s inside it to `CompositeCurve` one-by-one and add it to `Entities`.

Now, is there any way of converting it to `Region`s so the end result looks better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UtilityEx.GetConnectedCurves()` and `UtilityEx.DetectRegionFromContours()` methods as explained in this article: https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008270987-Extruding-DWG-DXF-profiles-